# Why don't my img display and CSS apply?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm begining in html/css, I'm trying to make a small website but I've got a issue : When I try to display a picture on my index.html page, nothing except the alt is shown. The same happens for the link to the CSS thing.

It seems my web browser isn't able to get the file, maybe some problem with the permissions/rights on the computer... The folders, every folders actually, on my computer have a square on "read only" on the proprieties (impossible to uncheck).

I googled it, but nothing works...

I'm on windows 7, tried with all browsers (IE8/9, FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari)...

My html was:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img href="image.jpg" alt"alternative text" />
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My css was:

```css
div {
    border-radius:5px;
    width:960px;
    height:45px;
}
```

Comment: `img` uses `src` , not `href`.

Comment: This is way too localised.

Comment: Check the network tab in the browser and confirm the permission error by getting a 404 on the file. If that request is 404 then get the admin to change permissions if your user account is unable to do this.

Comment: As Vucko mentioned u need to use src. Also make sure your relative paths. The path relative to your website is able to serve up "image.jpg"

Answer (score 2):

This means that the web server cannot get the image from the path that you have given. With your `img` tag you have provided the image will only be found if it resides in the same folder as that of the page which is showing the image. Also use `src` instead of `href`.

```
 <img src="image.jpg" alt="alternative text" />
```

Folder structure;

```
 index.html
 image.jpg
```

If your image is inside a folder you would have to do

```
 <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="alternative text" />
```

Folder structure

```
 index.html
 images // FOLDER
    image.jpg
```

You can also set an absolute path to get your image like below

```
 <img src="http://www.YOURWEBSITE.com/image.jpg" alt="alternative text" />
```

Folder structure

```
index.html
image.jpg
```

If the image was in a folder

```
 <img src="http://www.YOURWEBSITE.com/images/image.jpg" alt="alternative text" />
```

Folder structure

```
index.html
images // FOLDER
   image.jpg
```

Hope this helped

Comment: update it to `alt=...`

Comment: I really shouldn't copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

The img tag uses 'src' property.
You must write something like this

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt"alternative text" />
```

Before I had problem with folder copied form another hdd. The problem was something like this : the folder was accessible from me but the browser/server can't access this folder with images inside.
Fix : I copied all images from this folder and I delete the folder. I create a new folder with same name in same place and move the images inside this folder.

Hope I help you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have your html page, stylesheet.css and image.jpg on the same folder, as far as I know there is no 'i cant get te image even if i found it' error from the browser, as Vucko pointed out, img tags use **src** to specify it's location and not **href**.

You could also put a non breaking space inside it ** & nbsp ; **.